# Which reaction occurs in calcium vanadate when it comes in contact with water?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, materials, surface-chemistry, electrical-properties, thin-films

I am a physics student currently studying the electrical properties of $\ce{CaVO3}$ and I have noticed that the surface of my thin film samples, which were originally smooth and transparent, now have blue and orange spots all over. These spots vary in size, some being only a few $\pu{\mu m}$ or smaller and the largest being approximately $\pu{200 \mu m}$ across but consisting of many spots combined. Visually it appears like it might have been water condensation droplets that caused this after having been inside of a helium flow cryostat at temperatures between $\pu{4 K}$ and room temperature. I have also noticed a change in the electrical properties of my samples, which I might be able to understand if I know what sort of compound these spots are. I do not know for certain that these spots were caused by a reaction with water, I am purely basing this on the visual appearance of droplets.

The change in the electrical properties has happened over time. I first measured the properties when the samples were new and a year later I repeated these measurements and noticed an increase in the resistivity for the entire temperature range as well as a change in the charge carrier density, accompanied by these colorful spots, which makes me believe that they may be responsible for it. The spots are too small to be measured individually with my methods.

Comment: Are your film samples made of pure calcium vanadate ? Why study calcium vanadate ? Why study calcium vanadate at 4K? Which electrical properties have changed ?  Is this change due to the temperature ? to the humidity ? Does it happen only on your spots ?

Comment: @Maurice Yes, my samples are pure CaVO_3 and I study them to better understand the effects of electron correlation in correlated metals. Temperature-dependent measurements allow me to better understand what is happening in the system and 4K is the lowest temperature we can achieve at our lab and therefore the closest we can get to the ground state of the system.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304885309004399 might be of interest

Answer (score 3):

If you mean $\ce{Ca}\left( \ce{V}\ce{O_{3}} \right)_{2}$ aka $\ce{Ca} \ce{V_{2}}\ce{O_{6}}$ then $\ce{Ca} \ce{V_{2}}\ce{O_{6}} + 2 \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{O} \to \ce{Ca^{2+}} + 2 \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{V}\ce{O_{4}}^{-}$ should apply.
You can also find the reaction [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/calcium-vanadate) in equation $81$: $$
\ce{Ca_{n}}\ce{V_{2}}\ce{O_{5 + n}} + \left( 3 - n \right) \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{O} \to n \cdot \ce{Ca^{2+}} + 2 \cdot \ce{H_{3 - n}}\ce{V}\ce{O_{4}}^{n-}
$$ where $n = 1$.

So your calcium vanadate ($\ce{Ca}\left( \ce{V}\ce{O_{3}} \right)_{2}$) reacts with water ($\ce{H_{2}}\ce{O}$) to calcium ions ($\ce{Ca^{2+}}$) and [dihydroxy-oxido-oxovanadium](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/dihydrogenvanadate) ($\ce{H_{2}}\ce{V}\ce{O_{4}}^{-}$ aka $\ce{V}\ce{O_{2}}\left( \ce{O}\ce{H} \right)_{2}^{-}$).

The whole thing could theoretically continue to react at high enough temperatures: see [here](https://www.rsc.org/suppdata/c7/dt/c7dt02702h/c7dt02702h2.pdf) (page $8$)):
$$
4 \cdot \ce{V}\ce{O_{2}}\left( \ce{O}\ce{H} \right)_{2}^{-} \to \ce{V_{4}}\ce{O_{12}}^{-4} + 4 \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{O}
$$

But predicting the color of the whole thing is not that easy. On the one hand, there can be many other reactions, especially if your substance contains other particles. On the other hand, it's really difficult to find references for this. Also, more information would be useful, like its new properties.

---

> My material is actually $\ce{Ca}\ce{V}\ce{O_{3}}$

I would assume that $\ce{Ca}\ce{V}\ce{O_{3}}$ dissociates first in water:
$$
n \cdot \ce{Ca}\ce{V}\ce{O_{3}} + m \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{O} \rightleftharpoons n \cdot \left( \ce{Ca^{2+}} + \ce{V}\ce{O_{3}}^{2-} \right) + m \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{O}
$$

Because of the $\ce{V}\ce{O_{3}}^{2-}$ ion's peculiar electron configuration, I would assume that it would "steal" the hydrogen ($\ce{H}$) from the water ($\ce{H_{2}}\ce{O}$). The resulting oxygen in turn wants to react and could also react with the ion. This would result in something of the form:
$$
n \cdot \ce{Ca^{2+}} + m \cdot \ce{H_{2}}\ce{O} + n \cdot \ce{V}\ce{O_{3}}^{2-} \to n \cdot \ce{Ca^{2+}} + \left( n - w \right) \cdot \ce{V_{x}}\ce{O_{y}}^{z-} + \ce{R_{1}}
$$

If we let it dry again, we should just get a new calcium vanadate again (and some remaining part $\ce{R_{1}}$). Some vanadium-oxides are kinda yellow-orange or dark blue like [vanadium($\rm{IV}$)-oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanadium(IV)_oxide). Here $\left\{ w,\, x,\, y,\, z \right\} \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$, $n - w$ is the number of this special kind of vanadate (the vanadate $\ce{V_{x}}\ce{O_{y}}$), $x$ and $y$ are forming something which is supposed to imply the type of vanadate, $z$ is the electric charge of this vanadate / vanadate-ion and $\ce{R_{1}}$ is a remaining part resulting from the reaction, which in turn can be another vanadate or it can be a completely different compound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My material is actually CaVO$_3$ and sadly I have also not found references on this subject, especially for this form of calcium vanadate. I have included the change of electrical properties as an edit in my original post, I hope this helps.

Comment: The famous book by Cotton and Dickinson, Advanced Inorganic Chemistry, states that the blue oxide $\ce{VO2}$ can be fused with chalk and produce calcium vanadate $\ce{CaVO3}$ and ... "Little is known of its structure"...

Comment: @ Kevin Dietrich. Your last reaction is wrong. Calcium vanadate cannot produce $\ce{CaOH}$ in water, as this substance $\ce{CaOH}$ does not exist. Calcium hydroxyde is $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$

Comment: @Maurice Then I'll delete it.

Comment: @ Kevin Dietrich. Your new last reaction is wrong. It produces a strange stuff called $\ce{R1}$ which corresponds to nothing on the left hand side. This is the same for the parameters $w, x, y, z$, whose meaning is unknown.